# Directive communication - sharing a reference to an inner HTML element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to find a way to do clean communication between my two sibling directives. I want to implement "insertAtCaret" functionality for a textarea in one directive, to be called from another.

```
<text-holder ng-model='model.text' />
<text-inserter>
    <a ng-click='insert("hello")'>Hello</a>
</text-inserter>
```

`text-holder` turns into something like this:

```
<div class='my-class'>
    <h3>Enter some text:</h3>
    <textarea ng-model='ngModel'></textarea>
</div>
```

The `text-inserter` needs to insert stuff into that `textarea` - what's the cleanest angular-ish way to allow that communication? I want to be able to support multiple instances of that on the page. Should I just create a unique id for each one from a shared service? It seems a little unclean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can :

- Wrappe your directive in outer DOM element.
- create a communication directive on this element.
- Use the controller of this directive as an API for communication between the two directives.
- Use require from the two directive, to, set, the text.

  ```
  <div text-com-directive>
  <text-holder ng-model='model.text' />
  <text-inserter>
      <a ng-click='insert("hello")'>Hello</a>
  </text-inserter>
  </div>
  ```

Directive :

```
    directive('textComDirective', function(){
    return {
       scope:{},
       controller: function($scope){
           // create functions that will be used to set/use the text inserter.
       }   
    }
    });
```

Comment: Wrapping them seems not very reusability-friendly, because I'd have to remember to wrap them everywhere I use them, I would prefer a closer solution, something I can define on the elements themselves. So I understand how to use a shared service - but how would I support multiple on the same page? How would I say that this `text-holder` talks to that `text-inserter`?

Answer (score 0):

The only chain between two directives is a variable that is supposed to be updated, this is also used by both directive. The text-inserter directive is sort of like choosing the method to be executed to the text-holder

> html

```
<text-holder ng-model='model.text'></text-holder>
    <text-inserter>
      <a ng-click='model.insert("hello")'>Hello</a>
    </text-inserter>
```

> script.js

```
var app = angular.module('testapp',[]);
app.controller('appController', function ($scope) {

  $scope.model = {text: 'sample', insert: function(a){$scope.model.text = a}};

})

app.directive('textInserter', function () {
      return {
      restrict: 'E',
      trasclude: true // important to keep the content that is defined outside of directive
    }
});
```

[Sample](http://plnkr.co/edit/lpOkbHJfE2FPQuBTiLQu?p=preview)

The `insert` function is set in the controller that is holding the variable to pass to the directive, this way helps us to easy understand what logic should be applied and is going to happen for the model variable in the initiated scope it self.
The more benefit is you can situational change the behavior for some specific instance.

Comment: right, but I didn't want to simply update the model, I wanted to insert into the textarea at a specific place (insert at caret), the model doesn't have a reference to that textarea. How can I get a nice reference to it?

Comment: @Madd0g I don't get your point about 'insert at caret'. My point is updating the model, it also updates the text area as well.
Could you please to tell me a sample to clarify what're you going to do with the textarea when you get the "nice reference"?